# How to make reusable conditions that can be used in queryables?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

So in a function I've a large queryable and I apply a bunch of where cause on it based on other conditions.

Like in this example:

```
query.Where(i => 
    _context.FicDernierEvt
        .Where(y => y.VteAffaire == null && y.ApvAffaire == null)
        .Select(y => y.IdFicheCrm)
        .Contains(i.Id)
);
```

I've this condition `_context.FicDernierEvt.Where(y => y.VteAffaire == null && y.ApvAffaire == null).Select(y => y.IdFicheCrm).Contains(i.Id)` that is used a lot in my code.

I would like to avoid having this all accross my code so i've tried to make a function:

```
private bool isProspect(FicFicheCrm ficheCrm){
    return _context.FicDernierEvt
        .Where(y => y.VteAffaire == null && y.ApvAffaire == null)
        .Select(y => y.IdFicheCrm)
        .Contains(ficheCrm.Id);
}
```

So i could use it this way:

```
query.Where(i => isProspect(i));
```

But it didn't worked since, it's just not mean to be done that way.

Do someone have an idea on how to make reusable conditions like this to be used in queryables ?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to extend LINQ with a Where method that contains your predicate.

If you are not familiar with Extension methods, consider to read [Extension Methods Demystified](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/995/extension-methods-csharp)

You fogrot to tell us what type of `IQueryable<...>` you store in `_context.FicDernierEvt`, but let's assume it is `IQueryable<FicDernierEvt>`. In other words, assume that _context.FicDernierEvt is a table of FicDernierEvts.

> **Requirement** Procedure `GetIdFics` (TODO: *invent proper name*) takes as input an `IQueryable<FicDernierEvt>`, keeps only those `ficDernierEvts` that have a null value for both properties `VteAffaire` and `ApvAffaire`, and returns from every remaining ficDernierEvt the value of property `ficDernierEvt.IdFic`

I don't know the type of `IdFic`, but let's assume it is an int

```
public static IQueryable<int> GetIdFics(         // TODO: invent proper name
    this IQueryable<FicDernierEvt> source)
{
    return source.Where(ficDernierEvt => ficDernierEvt.VteAffaire == null
                                      && ficDernierEvt.ApvAffaire == null)
    .Select(ficDernierEvt => ficDernierEvt.IdFic);
}
```

That's all!

Usage:

```
IQueryable<int> myIdFics = _context.FicDernierEvt.GetIdFics();
```

You say you have this Where/Select in a lot of places:

```
var oldIdFics = _context.FicDernierEvt
    .Where(ficDernierEvt.Date.Year < 2010)
    .GetIdfics();

var invalidIdFics = _context.FicDernierEvt.GetIdFics()
    .Where(idFic => idFic <= 0);
```

You can even use it in a more complicate LINQ statement:

```
IQueryable<FicDernierEvt> unpaidFicDernierEvts = this.GetUnpaidFicDernierEvts();
int customerId = this.GetCustomerId(customerName);
var largestUnpaidCustomerIdFic = unpaidFicDernierEvts
    .Where(unpaidEvt => unpaidEvt.CustomerId == customerId)
    .GetIdFics()
    .Max();
```